# Можно ли текст сделать жирнее, чем с параметром bold?

Tags: android, textview

Доброго времени суток!
Хочу узнать, можно ли задать степень жирности у TextView? 
Например у стандартного шрифта [Roboto](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto) есть вид **Ultra-Bold 900**, но вот встает вопрос, можно ли сделать текст таким?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стандартными средствами можно добиться только Bold/Normal/Italic/BoldItalic  ([пруф](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3atextStyle))

Как вариант - использование кастомного шрифта с нужными видом "жирности" для необходимого контрола. Почитать про кастомный шрифт [тут](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/)

Comment: да про кастомные средства я знаю, меня интересует именно стандартный

Comment: @Артур Пантелеев, автор ответа дал правильную ссылку, просто местный парсер не любит двоеточие в ссылках, замена двоеточия на %3a решает проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Да можно

```
font-weight: bold|bolder|lighter|normal|100|200|300|400|500|600|700|800|900
```

вот возможные значения для font-weight. Bold соответствует 700, значит 800 и 900 будут жирнее

Comment: а можно пример кода или разметки привести :)

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от используемого шрифта и размера текста, какая максимальная жирность вложена в шрифт такая она и будет максимальная